# AttributeError: 'Processor' object has no attribute 'dwollaProcessorTokenCreate'

Tags: plaid, dwolla

> > > client = Client(client_id='XXXXXXX',secret='XXXXXX',public_key='XXXXXX', environment='sandbox')
> > >       client.Processor.dwollaProcessorTokenCreate()
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >       AttributeError: 'Processor' object has no attribute 'dwollaProcessorTokenCreate'

Answer (score 0):

"dwollaProcessorTokenCreate" function from Processor class has been changed to "dwollaBankAccountTokenCreate",but in documentation "https://plaid.com/docs/dwolla/' but it is still mentioned "dwollaProcessorTokenCreate"

try client.Processor.dwollaBankAccountTokenCreate(access_token, 
account_id)